# LESS - set 3 variables depending on another variable's value

Tags: less, mixins, guard

I've got a mixin that accepts two parameters:

```
.build-logo(ab, 200px);
```

The first is an acronym string for one of our products, and the second is square width/height of the desired logo. What I need is a set of guarded mixins that test against the value of the first parameter - but here's where my knowledge of LESS falls short.

I think it needs to be something like this, but I can't get the syntax down:

```
.set-logo-colors() when (@acronym = 'ab') {
    @first-color: red;
    @second-color: green;
    @third-color: blue;
}
```

Then the 3 color variables declared above need to be available in the previously mentioned `.build-logo()` mixin.

Any help, tips, or advice is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write parameter specific mixins instead of using guards, like:

```
.set-logo-colors(ab) {
    @first-color: red;
    @second-color: green;
    @third-color: blue;
}
.set-logo-colors(bc) {
    @first-color: orange;
    @second-color: blue;
    @third-color: gray;
}
```

which will be executed when you pass the right parameter.

And to elaborate this approach a little, you could do something like:

```
.logo(@product) {
    .set-logo-colors(@product);
    .build-logo(@product, 200px);
}
```

and lets say build-logo looks like this

```
.build-logo(@a, @b) {
    product: @a;
    width: @b;
    color: @first-color;
}
```

by calling

```
.logo(ac);
```

you get:

```
product: ab;
width: 200px;
color: #ff0000;
```

### More than one product:

There will be a problem, if you call more than one product, the color variable will be already set and

```
.logo(bc);
```

will return:

```
product: bc;
width: 200px;
color: #ff0000;
```

which is not what we want.

So it would be better to start with a set of **multiparametric mixins**:

```
.build-logo(@a, @b, @color1, @color2, @colo3) {
    product: @a;
    width: @b;
    color: @color1;
}

.logo(ab, @size) {
    .build-logo (ab, @size, red, green, blue);
}

.logo(bc, @size) {
    .build-logo (bc, @size, green, orange, gray);
}
```

now calling

```
.logo(ab, 200px);
```

gives the same output as above, but it will not overlap/overwrite anything when calling it for another product. So:

```
.logo(bc,200px);
```

returns:

```
product: bc;
width: 200px;
color: #008000;
```

Comment: Excellent answer Martin, lots of information to think about. I'll try out some of these ideas and come back!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. A good place to try out things quickly is http://less2css.org/ ... I like it a lot when playing around with ideas.

Comment: This general idea was the way to go. It turns out I was having scoping issues, so breaking things out into 3 related mixins solved the problem without repeating too much code. One mixin to build the logo with default colors/sizes, one to test the value of the @product variable and set new colors, and one last mixin to apply those colors to the necessary rules to prevent repeating them over and over. When I get some time and revise this process, I'll edit my original question with the finished product.

Answer (score 2):

try a different approach:

```
.build-logo(@acronym, @width) when (@acronym = 'ab') {
    background-color: red;
}
.build-logo(@acronym, @width) when (@acronym = 'cd') {
    background-color: blue;
}
.build-logo(@acronym, @width) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MarZab, I was trying something similar to this when you answered. Unfortunately, it didn't pan out as well as I hoped since it ended up requiring me to write a lot of duplicate code.